# How to get the filepath of pdf file from raw folder?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
    File file = new File("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro_sad);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

it results from an error in file path. how to get the filepath?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think raw resources are accessible by external applications (which is what I think you're trying to do). Instead you should copy the file to an [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) or a [WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) folder and then use the path of the copy.